# How do I remove the 'learn' lightbulb button in Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Every time I open Illustrator and then create a new document, a blue background tooltip appears at the top right saying 'Catch up with What's New in Illustrator.' with an OK and a Remind me Later option. How do I remove this? I learn everything I need to know already outside of the Illustrator suggestion box and would prefer not to have to close this tooltip every time I start up Illustrator.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kindly open Illustrator, then Edit-preference-general, and uncheck 'show tooltips'.

[image]

Comment: But I need the tooltip for other parts of Illustrator. Is there a way I can just remove the learn tooltip from showing at startup each time and that only?

Comment: I think it does not work that way.

Comment: I need the tooltip in my swatches panel with the color labels for example

Comment: May I know which version of Illustrator you are using? Am using Illustrator 2020. I don't get the pop tour/ Pop Tips each time I open it.

Comment: I just downloaded and installed new version of illustrator last week

Comment: maybe it's because I installed it so recently Illustrator thinks I'm new to the software? Maybe I should restart my pc since I've had it on since then.

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: this is actually a problem if you spin up a clean  machine every time you boot.

Comment: At least the lightbulb doesn't have a face and personality ... yet!

Comment: Usually this type of tooltip is cleared by actually clicking through to do the tour, just once.

Comment: restarted my pc, now tooltip is gone :)

Comment: This doesn't work. I never have tooltips on. The box is always unchecked yet there it is again, every time I open Illustrator.